# Content Security Policy: cannot load Mixpanel in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, mixpanel

I've been struggling with this for the past day and there are little-to-no resources available online for integrating Chrome Extensions and Mixpanel. I'd like for this thread to by the one that people refer to when dealing with integrating Mixpanel into a Chrome extension.

**The goal of my Mixpanel integration is to be able to track events both with my content script `content.js` as well as my `popup.js` (so basically across my whole extension)**

I have a popup.html file that calls `<script src="mixpanel.js"></script>` right before the `</head>` tag.

In my `mixpanel.js` file is:

```
(function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src=("https:"===e.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+'//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js';f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f);b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==
typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,
e,d])};b.__SV=1.2}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);

mixpanel.init("MY_TOKEN");
```

When I click on my extension's button and inspect it, the console outputs the following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://cdn.mxpnl.com".
```

Here is the permissions section of my `manifest.json` file:

```
"permissions": ["https://twitter.com/"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.mxpnl.com; object-src 'self'"
```

The extension needs to work on Twitter.

I've read the [Content Security Policy doc](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) that Google wrote which has not been helpful

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that Chrome doesn't allow extensions to load [remote resources over plain HTTP](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script); only HTTPS is allowed:

> As man-in-the-middle attacks are both trivial and undetectable over HTTP, those [i.e., `http:`] origins will not be accepted.

Your `mixpanel.js` script attempts to load `http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js` instead of the corresponding `https:` link. To fix this, simply change the line:

```
a.src=("https:"===e.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+'//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js'
```

to:

```
a.src='https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js'
```

It's currently loading the `http:` version because `window.location.protocol` is `chrome-extension:`, rather than `https:`. This change simply forces loading of the `https:` version always.

Comment: @Apsilers, Thank you so much. I hope this helps others who come across it. Going to forward to Mixpanel too so they have it in their Knowledge Base.

Comment: @ZackShapiro I think an even more general solution would be to change the ternary to `("https:"===e.location.protocol||"chrome-extension:"===e.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")` so it automatically uses `https:` for Chrome extensions and HTTPS pages, but uses `http:` in all other cases.

Comment: @ZackShapiro, I'm encountering the same issue as you are -- do you have the full sample of your popup.js, content.js, and manifest (or a link to the code?) I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 5):

The above answer incomplete. You have to do one more thing.

### Step 1: Adding HTTPS

Do what the other answer told you to do, change the mixpanel code, change

`http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js`

to

`https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js`

### Step 2: Modifying content security in your `manifest.json`

Update the `content_security_policy` property in your `manifest.json`:

`{
  ...,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js; object-src 'self'",
  ...
}`

This relaxes the default content security policy.

### Step 3 [optional]: Adding Google Analytics

If you also want Google Analytics as well, you can add it like this:

`{
  ...,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js; object-src 'self'",
  ...
}`

I learned how to do this from Google's own tutorial on **[how to add Google Analytics](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script to load mixpanel from custom url.

```
<script>
  window.MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL = 'lib/mixpanel/mixpanel.js';
</script>
```

Comment: how do you provide your token?